# update table in mysql with dynamically created input field from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update fields in database. here is the code in which i fetch the records from database and show them in a form.

```
<form name="create_album" method="POST" action="" style="width:auto;">

<label for="First Name">Album Name</label>

<input type="text" name="album" id="album" placeholder="Album Name"value="<?php echo $album_name; ?>" />


<?php 
$result = mysql_query("select * from user_uploads where album = '$album_name' ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<img src="<?php echo $row['image_name']; ?>" height="140" width="140" /> 
<input type="text" name="des[]" value="<?php echo $row['image_description']; ?>" placeholder="Image Description Here"/>
<input type="text" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" placeholder="Image Description Here"/>

<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Album"/>
```

but now when i want to update the records in database it update all the records into the table with the value of last input field. here is the php code.

```
  <?php 
if(IsSet($_POST["submit"]))
{
     $album = $_POST["album"];
             $des=$_POST["des"];
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $id)
    {

$update_qry = "update user_uploads set album='$album', image_description='$des' where id = '$id' ";

     $result_update_image = mysql_query($update_qry);
  if (!$result_update_image) 
  {
            header("location:create_album.php?errmsg=Album Not Updated");
        }



        }

    }
    }
 ?>
```

But i dont know how to get all the values of des form array to update in table according to id.

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: <input type="text" name="des[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['image_description']; ?>" placeholder="Image Description Here"/> this field is creadted dynamically from db records. now i want to update each image description simuntainously. but my code update all records by last image description value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code like this and check.

```
   $i=0;
    $des=$_POST["des"];
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $id)
        {

          $update_qry = "update user_uploads set album='".$album."', image_description='".$des[$i]."' where id = '".$id."' ";

         $result_update_image = mysql_query($update_qry);
    $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="des[]" value="<?php echo $row['image_description']; ?>" placeholder="Image Description Here"/>
```

I have changed the name.

Comment: i already tried this but same problm. only last image description value update in all records

Comment: @ApoorvaChauhan, just try print of post values as print_r($_POST) and check what values your getting in variables. what is that $album_name value

Comment: @ApoorvaChauhan check your where condition.Will your album_name be unique as the loop proceeds??

Comment: @Shafeeq if i print the values it printsonly last input field value. $album_ name value is the album name in which image description will be updated. album name successfully updated. in this code.

Comment: @sanal k yes album name is unique. but in a album there are several images. so i want to update each row where album name is $album_name simuntainously with the image name.

Comment: @ApoorvaChauhan, in all array dec value, then check the output of <?php echo $row['image_description']; ?>. else check the input name <input type="text" name="des[]"

Comment: input name is same but values are different. but in update query it takes only last value.

Comment: @ApoorvaChauhan echo the query $update_qry = "update user_uploads set album='$album', image_description='$des' where album = '$album_name'"; and check where problem occurs

Comment: @ApoorvaChauhan eg for album=1,you will be having imqge1.jpg,imqge2.jpg,imqge3.jpg etc right? then if you are having album=$album_name in where condition,it will update every rows in one shot.

Comment: problm still persist. plz help me. how to update two arrysdata simuntaniously in db.

Comment: @ApoorvaChauhan Yes you have to update it with id of the image.